# UIProgressView not updated

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiprogressview

I have a UIProgressView that I am trying to change the progress but is is never updated.
My "slow" operation is done from a NSoperation/NSOperation queue so it should be multithreaded.

Did you already experienced this or do you have any idea to solve this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Could you put your code here please? Without any help it's hard to find your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Updates to the user interface should usually be done on the main thread. Try using `-performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` to update your `UIProgressView`.

Comment: You will also want to make sure that the waitUntilDone argument is NO when doing this to get this to update properly in certain cases.